# how to sum an array in dictionary

Tags: python, arrays

i have a dictionary , and i want to sum for every array in every key dictionary

```
example :
{'Ancolmekar': array([1]),
'Cidurian': array([1]),
'dayeuhkolot': array([1]),
'Hantap': array([1]),
'Kertasari': array([1]),
'Meteolembang': array([1]),
'Sapan': array([1]),
 }
```

the value 1 is example not a real calculated. what i supposed to do?

this is my dictionary it name DP_1

```
{'Ancolmekar': array([-0.07603596, -0.09520354, -0.09629883, -0.08370299, -0.13408635,
        -0.14558689, -0.14421778, -0.14367014, -0.14175338, -0.14038426,
        -0.15161099, -0.12340727, -0.0995847 ,  0.03568364,  0.28075484,
         0.46180632,  0.41755659,  0.32171869,  0.19066721,  0.09647225,
        -0.02620026, -0.0073065 , -0.10122764, -0.09438207]),
 'Cidurian': array([-0.15732019, -0.17139467, -0.17468054, -0.18557868, -0.17933552,
        -0.19193136, -0.17851406, -0.19494341, -0.19795546, -0.19220518,
        -0.17851406, -0.16098941, -0.03667397,  0.13879153,  0.38254838,
         0.55637094,  0.51726908,  0.355659  ,  0.25346842,  0.20335889,
         0.01294268,  0.01370938, -0.10425338, -0.1298284 ]),
 'Dayeuhkolot': array([-0.04123083, -0.05256709, -0.06341046, -0.0514718 , -0.0684488 ,
        -0.06625821, -0.06543675, -0.06571057, -0.07419907, -0.07764923,
        -0.07858023, -0.0599603 , -0.05081462,  0.06271221,  0.11780531,
         0.22519852,  0.18954682,  0.14661145,  0.07941539,  0.06336939,
         0.01616238, -0.00661966, -0.0226109 , -0.05585296]),
 'Hantap': array([-0.04986537, -0.07067589, -0.06793766, -0.05808005, -0.0575324 ,
        -0.06755431, -0.07067589, -0.072045  , -0.06684237, -0.07752145,
        -0.072045  , -0.07368793, -0.04384127,  0.01064942,  0.13195281,
         0.17822882,  0.17450484,  0.14898457,  0.15506344,  0.12236902,
         0.0085136 , -0.02270217, -0.02303076, -0.03622901]),
 'Kertasari': array([-0.13810469, -0.1709634 , -0.1794519 , -0.17863043, -0.17999954,
        -0.1794519 , -0.18848804, -0.19150009, -0.1988933 , -0.1819163 ,
        -0.16630842, -0.06143437,  0.05932138,  0.16967187,  0.48949662,
         0.54239914,  0.44842324,  0.29699936,  0.23095336,  0.13653934,
         0.02213627, -0.10716274, -0.12978049, -0.14385497]),
 'Meteolembang': array([-7.71175612e-02, -9.71066083e-02, -1.07785688e-01, -9.73804308e-02,
        -9.05348667e-02, -1.06142753e-01, -9.98448339e-02, -1.10250091e-01,
        -1.09428624e-01, -1.13262139e-01, -1.06142753e-01, -1.73420957e-04,
         1.07165024e-01,  1.21129974e-01,  2.79508945e-01,  1.29289887e-01,
         2.62970062e-01,  2.07384082e-01,  1.42214312e-01,  2.77564805e-02,
        -2.23530486e-02, -3.57703541e-02, -3.44012413e-02, -6.97243520e-02]),
 'Sapan': array([-0.04793492, -0.05461619, -0.06419998, -0.06639056, -0.06365234,
        -0.06995026, -0.0559853 , -0.0680335 , -0.07405759, -0.07323613,
        -0.07843876, -0.0729623 , -0.05242561, -0.00587578,  0.13240462,
         0.16663244,  0.22769487,  0.16586574,  0.13229509,  0.06477045,
         0.07002784, -0.02285277, -0.02783635, -0.0612427 ])}
```

Comment: What language is this? Please tag it correctly

Comment: this is python language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce function as below:

```py
from functools import reduce
dict2 = {}
for k, v in dict.items():
    dict2[k] = reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, v)

print(dict2)
```